# Do State diagrams Only Represent Individual Objects states?

Tags: design, uml, finite-state-machine

On website uml-diagrams.org it is mentioned that state machine diagram is a behavior diagram which shows discrete behavior of **a part of designed system through** finite state transitions. To the best of my knowledge, state charts represent the states of a single object of a certain class. What is meant by part of the system in this case? Can state diagram represent something other than one object?

Comment: Consider two rooms, a door in between and  a dog. Dog can't go through a closed door. Would two separate state diagrams of a door and a dog be of any use?

Answer (score 3):

> Can state diagram represent something other than one object?

Yes. A state diagram shows the states and transitions of a single instance of something. That something can be a class (in which case the instance is called an object), but it can also be a larger structure, like a module, sub-system or even the entire system.

If you take the classic example of an ATM, you can draw a state diagram of an ATM, but in most cases you will further decompose your ATM (sub-)system into multiple classes because it is just too much to handle it all in a single class.

Comment: Does this mean I can represent a sub-system, which for example, includes state such as authenticating, displaying menu, updating database, etc, with events/guards such as enter username, [valid username],  click on update, etc. ??? Then how this would differ from flow chart?

Comment: yes, technically you can do it. Practically it will be more difficult to read than other approaches. But the language itself lets you do it.

Comment: thanks. Could you recommend any books/tutorials that show examples of this?

Comment: @AfiaR.S. A flow chart depicts flow of control through the steps of a process - you can think of it as being a picture of an algorithm. While a state diagram can look superficially similar, conceptually, it does *not* depict "steps" or associated implementation details, but a set of abstract states (or "modes" or "dispositions" that have some meaning in the context of the problem you're trying to solve), and transitions between them - which have to be *triggered* (for the original notion predating UML, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_diagram)).

Comment: @AfiaR.S. See also the Wikipedia article on [FSMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). Framing the problem in terms of a FSM is different then thinking in terms of an algorithm you might implement in a general-purpose programming language; FSMs are a simpler, more constrained model of computation.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović  Many thanks for the clarification.  If you can think of an example which shows a "subsystem" being modelled by state diagram I would extremely appreciate it if you let me know.